# Can I get refund from IRCTC?

Tags: trains, tickets, india, refunds, tatkal

I am going to travel from Manmad to *** *****, we are 4 people out of which 1 got his ticket confirmed through the IRCTC portal for Indian Railways though other 3 are under CKWL/TATKAL waiting list. We all want to travel together but I am not sure if we would get the confirmed tickets for sure by tomorrow. My question is that will we get full money refunded as we applied for tickets through the IRCTC portal but only one got confirmed and other 3 aren't.

EDIT: Current Status CHART PREPARED - 1 ticket confirmed and 3 waiting list.  I didn't get refund for even the waiting list tickets either!

Well, I got a mail from IRCTC and following is their reply.

> Dear Customer,  With Reference to your PNR No:8221438***, we regret to
>   inform you that refund is not admissible as informed by Railways
>   through their letter no : BNR230214V61091 and the reason being : 'No
>   refund is granted for TATKAL CONFIRMED ticket'
>
> In case you require any further assistance, please mail us at
>   tdrprocess@irctc.co.in  With regards,  TDR TEAM

My Reply -

> There were  4 tickets over all, out of which only 1 had got confirmed
>   and remaining 3 were in the waiting list. Since the 3 waiting list
>   tickets didn't get confirm. I am entitled to get refund for those 3
>   tickets.
>
> Booking details: PNR No    8221438*** Train No     12165 Train Name    LTT
>   BSB SUP EXP   From     MMR To  ET Date     17-2-2014 Class     SL Boarding Point
>   MMR Reservation Upto   ET Quota    Tatkal
>
> Regards, Gauraw

**I called IRCTC customer care, and they said - It is must to cancel all the tickets not just the confirmed one. The ticket wouldn't be cancelled automatically (" the entire Tatkal ticket is surrendered for cancellation within six hours before the scheduled departure of the train or upto two hours of the actual departure of the train.").**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called IRCTC customer care, and they said - It is must to cancel all the tickets not just the confirmed (for this particular scenario). The ticket wouldn't be cancelled automatically ("The entire Tatkal ticket should be surrendered for cancellation within six hours before the scheduled departure of the train or up to two hours of the actual departure of the train.").

What I did wrong was that I thought If I would cancel the confirmed ticket all tickets would be canceled since all the tickets share the same pnr number, I think IRCTC's policy sucks and it's a way to earn money from users. Logically speaking this policy doesn't make sense to me and I think it should be changed.

Answer (score 6):

If you cancel your tickets, you will get the refund for three persons, minus the clerkage charges at INR 30 each.

You will not refund for the confirmed ticket (one person on your ticket) as you made the booking under **Tatkal Quota** (This assumption is based on the fact that the other people on your ticket are under CKWL, which is waiting list for Tatkal quota).

Even if you don't cancel your ticket, and the remaining three seats are not confirmed and stay on waiting list, the tickets for the three will be automatically cancelled, and the balance amount reverted into your account you used to book the tickets.

Comment: How long does it take to get refund for waiting list tickets?

Comment: @GaurawYadav There is no official timelimit from IRCTC about this, but I got my last refund in 2 days. To quote from IRCTC website "IRCTC's payment reconciliation team works on a 24 x 7 basis, IRCTC offers no guarantees whatsoever for the accuracy or timeliness of the refunds reaching the Customers card/bank accounts. This is on account of the multiplicity of organizations involved in processing of online transactions, the problems with Internet infrastructure currently available and working days/holidays of financial institutions."

Comment: Thank you Incognito, It's been over for 15 days for me, and Today I received a mail that I won't get any refund.

Comment: Follow up with them about the 3 waiting tickets on the Tatkal quota.

Answer (score 6):

If you have One PNR for all passengers (that is one ticket for all (4) passengers) than according to rules you will get refund minus charges

"Refund on Tatkal tickets:

No refund of fare shall be admissible on confirmed Tatkal ticket.
In case of Tatkal ticket on waitlist, refund of fare shall be granted inaccordance with rule for unused waitlisted or RAC tickets.
In case on a party Tatkal ticket or a family Tatkal ticket issued for travel for more than one person, some persons have confirmed reservation and others are on waiting list, full refund of fare, less clerkage, shall be admissible for confirmed passengers also provided that the **entire Tatkal ticket is surrendered for cancellation within six hours before the scheduled departure of the train or upto two hours of the actual departure of the train."**